# How to get response time in angular 4

Tags: angular, api, http, google-chrome-devtools

I want to calculate the response time taken by each request. Currently I am sending 50 requests to a service and I am getting responses after all the requests are sent. So I'm unable to calculate the time taken for each response as there are 49 requests after the first call.I am using http module and not http client module.  I feel the chrome developer tools is giving a correct response time but how do I capture it in angular 4 ?

[image: I think it is the waiting time in below picture]

Comment: Most of the performance statistics are available through an API in the Chrome Developer Tools. Can you tell us how you want to access the API? Client code of your served web page cannot access that API and that information.

Comment: I am already accessing the API which is in my local machine and I'm getting data from database . I am making async calls to the service in a for loop and waiting for all the 50 results to come. When the results are available I am binding them. As it is async call I am not able to figure out the time taken to get response.

Comment: No, Imeant accessing the Chrome Developer Tools API, especially the  Resource Timing stuff https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#type-ResourceTiming

Comment: I am trying to access it from client side. I.e  from angular application. console.time()  and console.timeEnd() , this is not working for me.

Comment: No. You cannot access the Chrome Developer Tools from an arbitrary client within the web page you're serving. Which is where my question started out. You tagged the question with "google-chrome-devtools", and if you want to get information from the Chrome Developer Tools, you will need to access the Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Thanks, but but I wanted the response time that is shown in dev tools which is not happening.

Comment: If you want the response time, you need to go in Chrome where the response time is. That time can be accessed using the Chrome Developer Tools API.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple interceptor that shows the time for each request from the angular perspective. You can actually modify it to include the time along with the response... I'm not sure how you want to use the time.

```js
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { defer } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class PerformanceInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return defer(() => {
      const key = req.urlWithParams;
      console.time(key);
      return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize(() => {
        console.timeEnd(key);
      }));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just as same. I can get the values by not using interceptor too because i am getting http response after 50 requests made. But thanks anyways.

Comment: @AnkushRanapure I don't get it. This will show the time between the request and the response, for each request... (do they have same url?) What was your question?

Comment: Andrei: are you using this successfully? I agree that it should work but I'm seeing quite a discrepancy between what is measured here and what the network tab or the performance API is measuring. E.g. the time measured with the interceptor would say something is taking 200ms, while the network tab says 20ms. Of course the network tab is more low level, but we're talking about 10x as long. `window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource').find(e => e.name === 'the-url')` has yet another duration, in this case 100ms :)

Comment: @Christof well, I guess it depends. Might be other interceptors that do other stuff in the meanwhile. There's also deserialization of the response probably...